# I have Julia BoundsError

Tags: julia

I want to make svd alg. but i have BoundsError. Below is my code.

```
function house(x::Array{Float64})

    n = length(x)
    sigma = dot(x[2:n]', x[2:n])
    nu = [1; x[2:n]]
    beta = 0
    if sigma == 0
        beta = 0
    else
        mu = sqrt(x[1]^2 + sigma)
        if x[1] <= 0
            nu[1] = x[1] - mu
        else
            nu[1] = -sigma / (x[1]+ mu)
        end
        beta = 2nu[1]^2 / (sigma + nu[1]^2)
        nu =nu / nu[1]
        nu, beta
    end
end

function house_bidiag(A)

    A = copy(A)
    m,n = size(A)
    for j = 1:n
        nu, beta = house(A[j:m,j]) # this part, i got error
        A[j:m,j:n] = (eye(m-j+1)- beta*nu*nu')*A[j:m,j:n]
        A[j+1:m,j] = nu[2:m-j+1]
        if j <= n-2
            nu, beta = house(A[j,j+1:n]')
            A[j:m,j+1:n] = A[j:m,j+1:n] * (eye(n-j)-beta*nu*nu')
            A[j,j+2:n] = nu[2:n-j]'
        end
    end
    A
end

M=rand(5,7)
house_bidiag(M)
```

In indexed_next at base\tuple.jl: 35 and I do not know what's wrong with the trace. The Julia version is using 0.5.1.

Comment: Please report exactly how you call the function and the complete error message. From that it should be clear e.g. In which line the error occurred.

Comment: "I do not know what's wrong with the trace." Please post what you're asking questions about.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see here [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3):

The functions `house` returns only `0` if `sigma == 0`, not the tuple `nu, beta`. In particular, this happens if the argument of `house` is an empty array.

In the line you marked, you try to destructure the return value of `house` into the variables `nu` and `beta`. But this is only possible for iterables with at least two elements and therefore fails for a single number like `0`.

To fix this error, you can move the tuple `nu, beta` out of the `else` block in `house`.

However, in the case `j>m`, `eye((m-j)+1)` returns a `0×0 Array{Float64,2}` while `beta * nu * nu'` returns a `1×1 Array{Float64,2}`. Trying to subtract these causes a `DimensionMismatch` error. Because I don't know what you actually want to achieve, I can't propose a fix here.